# How to pass a string type inside subject.next()

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to show username on navbar when a user is logged in, I have created a BehaviourSubject to do the job, however, a problem that I'm facing right now is when i pass in "exp" or "iat" vars inside "this.getLoggedInName.next(IN HERE)", It shows the variable on the navbar, but when I pass in any other variables such as "username" or "id", nothing shows (also tried to log the variable in console and got "undefined"). Please Help!!! Here is my auth.service.ts

```
export interface UserDetails{
  username: string
  email: string
  password: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  exp: number
  iat: number
  id: string
```

```
export class AuthenticationService {

public getLoggedInName = new Subject();

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

public getUserDetails(): UserDetails{
    const token = this.getToken()
    let payload
    if(token){
      payload = token.split('.')[1]
      payload = window.atob(payload)
      
      return JSON.parse(payload)
      
    }else{
      return null
    }
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean{
    const user = this.getUserDetails()
    if(user){
      this.getLoggedInName.next(user.username); // Here is where I'm trying to pass in user.username but it doesn't show anything. Only shows when i pass in "username.exp"
      return user.exp > Date.now()/ 1000 
      
    }
    else{
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my header component

```
export class HeaderComponent{

username: any

constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.auth.getLoggedInName.subscribe(name => this.username = name);
}
```

header.html

```
<li *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn()" ><a routerLink="/profile">{{username}}</a></li>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You've confirmed your user object has those other fields populated e.g. userName is something other than undefined or an empty string?

Comment: I've tried with every field, they all return "undefined" in my console. If that's what you are asking

Comment: Right, but ignoring the next() part of it, if you console.log(user) do you see what you expect to see? i.e. the user object has the values in it? If it's empty then the problem lies elsewhere than your Subject.

Comment: you're right, when I do console.log(user), I only see the "iat" and "exp" field, and not anything else. It seems like the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Yep, so it's probably in your getToken() method. It isn't returning everything it should be.

Comment: Would you mind if I can get your social media or something so I can ask you a few questions?